# issue with geting all data from sqflite database

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i have been trying to get all my data from a sqflite database, when i try to get a single data, this works totally fine:

```
Future<dynamic> getUser() async {
final db = await database;
var res = await db.query("files");
if (res.length == 0) {
  return null;
} else {
  var resMap = res[0];
  return resMap;
 }
}
```

but when i try to get all data using a for loop like the example below, i get an error

```
Future<dynamic> getUser() async {
  final db = await database;
  var res = await db.query("files");
  var resMap;
  var count = res.length;
  if (count != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      resMap.add(res[i]);
    }
  }

  return resMap;
}
```

the error says:

```
The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => Null)
```

i understand that it says that I've got no data,
and i also tried to remove the if statement, but still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

change this method:

EDIT

```dart
Future<List<Map>> getUser() async {
  final db = await database;
  var res = await db.query("files");
  List<Map> resMap = [];
  if (res != null res.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      resMap.add(res[i]);
    }
    return resMap;
  } else
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: sadly the problem still occurs,
i've read somewhere that i have to change the type of resMap to a map, could you please let me know how can it be happen?

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i really appreciate it,
now i don't get any errors, but i can't see anything on my screen,

could you help me with that?

Comment: I put another answer for your widget

Comment: thank you so much, it worked, i really don't know how to thank you enough
really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this in you widget

```dart
      List<Map> newUser = [];

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getUser();
      }

      getUser() async {
        final _userData = await DBProvider.db.getUser();
        if(_userData != null ){
          setState(() {
            newUser = _userData;
          });
        } else{
          setState(() {
            newUser =[];
          });
        }
      }
```